# makecert just repeats command line over and over

Tags: cmd, makecert

I have copied makecert.exe to my System32 folder and used the following command on lots of PCs

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

but for a couple of PCs (With no obvious difference to the others) it behaves strangely as in it just keeps repeating what I have wrote so I end up with

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

`makecert -r -pe -n "CN=JOHNCERT" -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2099 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -ss My`

And this keeps going forever (but the certificate is never created). I have to press Ctrl+C to stop it going.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen. I've tried as Admin and limited user on Win 7 Pro 64-Bit

Thanks
John

Comment: You didn't call your batch file `makecert` did you?

Comment: No I don't have a batch file. I simply open CMD and type that command and on 99% of PCs it just completes immediately but this one just keeps repeating my command and never completes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, realised my mistake now.

I normally copy makecert.exe to the users C:\Windows\System32 folder but for some reason I got hold of a MakeCert.bat batch file and placed that in there instead. Sorry for the time wasting!

Thanks for the reply anyway
John

Comment: Please use your registered account - http://stackoverflow.com/users/2463687/user2463687 - then you'll be able to comment on answers. You can get the accounts merged by filling out the form here - http://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge